# Is there any shortcut key to switch between .cc and .h in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, key, eclipse-cdt

Is there any shortcut key to switch between .cc and .h in Eclipse CDT?

I was using visual stdio , I can switch between .cc and .h using alt+o,

Can I do it in Eclipse CDT?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ctrl+Tab` is the default shortcut in eclipse for switching the editor view from viewing a `.cpp` file to a corresponding `.h` file, and vice versa.

YES, You can change it to `alt+o`

In `Window->Preferences->General->Keys - Toggle Source/Header`

Answer (score 1):

Pressing Ctrl-Tab while in a .c/.h file works for me. But not sure if it is a thing from the CDT plugin to eclipse.